# What is meant by a|a notation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

`Is the "divides" relation on set of positive integer reflexive?`

In solution of above question I found following.

`Because a|a whenever a is a positive integer,the "divides" relation is reflexive`.

My question is what does `a|a` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $m$ and $n$ are integers, $m\mid n$ means that there is an integer $k$ such that $n=km$, i.e., that $n$ is a multiple of $m$, or $m$ is a divisor of $n$ (‘$m$ *divides* $n$’). In particular, if $a\in\Bbb Z^+$, then certainly $a=1\cdot a$, so $a\mid a$. The *divides* relation is therefore reflexive on $\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: @Luis: I actually meant the other way around, but yes, I definitely hit the wrong key; thanks!